# How do I select a JS tab in watir-webdriver?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a webpage which has tab list, the HTML looks like this for this piece:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="col span-6">
<div class="section first no-border">
<h2>New Search</h2>
<ul class="tabs clear">
<li id="simple-li" class="current">
<a onclick="switch_search_type('SimpleSearch');; return false;" href="#">Simple</a>
</li>
<li id="structured-li">
<a onclick="redirect_to_search('/search/structured_searches/new'); return false;"     href="#">Wizard</a>
</li>
<li id="advanced-li" class="">
</li>
<li id="custom-li" class="">
<a onclick="switch_search_type('ComplexQuerySearch');; return false;" href="#">Custom</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tabbed-panel">
```

I want to select the "Custom" item in this tab list. I tried multiple things but have failed, some of the things I tried:

```
browser.li(:id, "custom-li").click
browser.select_list(:id, "custom-li").set("Custom")
browser.link(:xpath, "id('custom-li')/x:a").click
browser.select_list(:id => 'custom-li').select "Custom"
```

I am new to watir-webdriver. Any feedback and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.a(:text => "Custom").click
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer then. :) Since you are new to watir, I would recommend to start with the free version of my watir book: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads

Comment: Accepting the answer as the correct one is enough. :) Thanks.